# How to get https Google search if it is "turned off" in your network?

Tags: https, google-search

When searching on Google over public WiFi at a cafe, I am getting the message:

> **SSL search is off**
>
> This network has turned off SSL search, so you cannot see personalized
>   results.
>
> The security features of SSL search are not available. Content filtering may be in place.

I can change the URL to `https://...`, but it switches back to `http` after submitting a search. How can I get back the secure search (without using a VPN)? I don't want everybody to see what I'm searching for.

This is probably caused by a - IMO ridiculous feature that lets network administrators disable Google's `https` search page for their network. I wonder if there is maybe a Firefox Addon that corrects this, or some way to bend my DNS records back to get the correct page. I am using Windows 8.1, if that matters.

Comment: Could you try to check if you have access to HTTPS port? In a command prompt `telnet www.google.com 443` or `openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443`. The wifi admins could have blocked all traffic on that port so they can monitor **everything** people send on their network. It's not ridiculous since, in some places, the owners of the network are legally responsibles for the harm anybody could do from their network.